Make SVG curves look smoother
I have created this svg border path.But the curves does not look smooth.  If I increase my stroke-width="1" the curves go away. (the edges and the arc in the between)
I want to make the stroke-width="10" minimum
How can i make it clean? I'm new to SVG's


.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
<div class="box">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 400 200">
    <path d="M 5 0  
             H 395
             Q 400 0 400 5     
             V 95
             Q 400 98 395 100  
             A 1 1, 0 0 0, 395 150
             Q 397 150 400 155
             V 195
             Q 400 200 395 200            
             H 5
             Q 0 200 0 195
             V 5
             Q 0 0 5 0
             " stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" stroke-width="1" />

  </svg>

</div>




Does this answer your question? how to solve svg path stoke width different thickness

Your issue is overflow: hidden on the SVG. The reason your curves get 'unrounded' when increasing the thickness is that one side of the thickness flows outside of the viewable area. Set overflow to visible and it will work. Then you could also add stroke-linejoin to rounded to stop the internal part of the curves squaring off.

@AndrewMorton all my strokes are inside the viewbox

@somethinghere overflow:visible did work. let me try the stroke-linejoin

@SandeepRanjan - You need to look into "spline continuity". On the right hand side of the figure, at the top of the cut-out, the right tangent to the end of the circle is not in line with the left tangent. This means that the line entering that point and the line exiting that point have a different gradient - this shows as  a weird fillet. The fillet on the bottom of the cutout is even worse. If you open the image in a visual editing program like Inkscape, this becomes immediately apparent.

@SandeepRanjan Please read the answer in the question I linked to, and then try viewbox="-2 -2 404 204" and see how the lines are a consistent thickness.

@AndrewMorton Understood.

@SandeepRanjan There is more information in the answers to Can you control how an SVG's stroke-width is drawn? (Answer: no.)

@enhzflep is there any way I can fix it without using a visual editing tool? When I fix the curve in Figma and try to export it, the 'd' attribute becomes complex and hard to edit/maintain. I need to use it in a React project and change the values of 'd' depending on props.

@SandeepRanjan If this is a one-off, pencil and paper will be the easiest way.

@SandeepRanjan - yes, of course. From a quick glance, here seems like a reasonable place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d - Have a look at the Cubic Bézier Curve and Quadratic Bézier Curve sections. Do be aware that this will involve a, ah "little" math. (thus the pencil and paper suggestion from Andrew)

thanks @AndrewMorton and enhzflep.  I have been reading mdn the whole day. Hopefully I will be able to solve it

pen paper did help d="M 5 0 H 395 Q 400 0 400 5 V 95 Q 400 100 395 100 A 1 1, 0 0 0, 395 150 Q 400 150 400 155 V 195 Q 400 200 395 200 H 5 Q 0 200 0 195 V 5 Q 0 0 5 0
this works great. All the tangents look correct in figma

looking at your svg in Figma, a design software, i can see that the path is not drawn as a perfect curve, and thus when making it thicker its noticeable (see attached screenshot).
Also noticed that putting the stroke-width more than one is only effecting the mentioned curve and not the rest of the path, which is an issue in my view.
Also pasting the SVG code in https://svgomg.net (free online SVG code optimization tool) the tool states that there is something wrong with it.
So all in all, i can guess that you are trying to write the path element yourself, which i have all the respect for because i don't know how to do that myself yet, but maybe you can try drawing it in a tool or try again manually if you like and that should fix your issue.


Reason why I'm trying to write the svg is becuase i need to put this in react and make changes to the values of D. if i do it in figma it gives me a complicated D attribute. Which is hard to understand and debug

@Araz The problem with the SVG in the question is that the outer half of the stroke is being drawn outside the viewbox - the stroke is centred on the path. (Please see my comments on the question for more information.)

yes i fully understand what you are trying to do... as stated before i sadly dont have the skills to draw an svg, maybe someone else can help with that. but you can maybe research if you can draw it a bit smoother or with an extra point or curve if necessary.
look at it from a different or new perspective. see if you notice something new in the value and see if that will fix your path data.

@AndrewMorton ohh! i see what you mean.... i thought that should draw it anyway and the points just dont draw if they are outside of the viewbox....
that might make sense... i recommend you posting an answer here with the suggestion so it would be credited to you correctly.

@Araz The person who deserves the credit is user chrwahl in their answer linked to in my earlier comment.
